# How ot give $this in Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am displaying datas in a grid ,on click of active or inactive button i have to change the button ,functionality is working fine ,for changing icon i am unable to find the active clicked button ,in jquery we can use "**this**"  ,but no idea in angular js ,pls help

```
 $scope.activeSource = function(datasource,status)
                {

                        $scope.loading = true;
                        $scope.activeInfo = {
                                datasource:datasource,
                        };
                        $scope.alerts = [];
                        if(status == "Stopped")
                        {
                            $scope.entityService.activeInfo($scope.activeInfo,
                            function( msg ) // success
                            {
                                $scope.loading = false;
                                $rootScope.successMsg.push(msg);
                                $('.icon-play').hide();  // this.
                                $('.icon-stop').show();  // this.  no idea

                            },
                            function( msg ) // error
                            {
                                $scope.loading = false;
                                $rootScope.successMsg.push(msg);
                            }
                        );
```

Comment: you are using ng-click?? Or how you sets that click handler on those buttons?

Comment: yea i am using ng-click,its inside the ng-grid ng-click="activeSource(row.entity.dataSource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `this` to access the button. Instead, in your controller create a javascript object that holds all the attributes for the button. Something like this:

```
$scope.myButton = {
  src : 'foobar.png',
  isVisible : true
};
```

Then, define your button like this:

```
<img ng-src="myButton.src" ng-show="myButton.isVisible" />
```

Now, when you want to modify any attribute of the button, you just need to change the javascript object `myButton`, and angular will take care of updating the actual button.

For example, if you want to hide the button:

```
// you don't need to do this
// $('#myButton').hide();

// instead just do this
$scope.myButton.isVisible = false;
```

Similarly, you can change the src of the image as well.

Comment: if he has 1000 of those buttons?

Comment: Then he probably needs to consider redesigning his UI. In answer to your facetious question, he can expect a slow down in the UI. Google, themselves, admit that Angular will experience slow downs when you near around 1000 bindings. If you're expecting those many bindings, then Angular isn't the right choice. You should probably consider something like Backbone that doesn't run a digest loop.